# API to Access "Open in other devices" from google

Tags: api, google-chrome

I am looking for an API that google may or may not have to let developers have access to users tabs they have open in other devices. Anyone know of such an API or a method of retrieving the urls?

Preferably Obj-C but python or something would be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome is based on the open source Chromium browser, which also has the 'open in other devices' feature.

You might want to check out the chromium developer documentation - esp. [the design documents related to the synch feature](http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/sync).

From what I understand, the browsing history, open in other devices, etc is a subset of the data synched via this feature.

Worst case you can download a copy of the chromium source and work it out from there.